# Unable to page/sort searched gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

Have been trying to solve this gridview problem for days.

I got 2 different gridviews with different information that are able to be sorted by clicking the header. There's also a paging function to organize the information. In addition to that, i also have a searched button where i can searched for all the information present in the gridview. However, only for the page_load gridview, the page/sort function work but the searched gridview was unable to page/sort.

I shall show you how i do the page/sort function for the one single default gridview.

Firstly, i need to  bind those gridview under a dataset like this and display the information upon page load

```
Session["gridview"] = DataBindByDataSet();
GVPolice.DataSource = Session["gridview"];
GVPolice.DataBind();

using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connAdd.Open();

                var sql = "select policeid as [Police ID], fullname as [Full Name], contact as [Contact], email as [Email], nric as [NRIC],  address as [Address], handle as [HandleCase], postedto as [Posted To] from PoliceAccount where status='available'";
                using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
                {
                    DataSet dsSel = new DataSet();
                    cmdAdd.Fill(dsSel);
                    GVPolice.DataSource = dsSel;
                    GVPolice.DataBind();
                }
```

I then bind the gridview under another method called datatable

```
private DataTable DataBindByDataSet()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                //conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI";
                conn.Open();

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select policeid as [Police ID], fullname as [Full Name], contact as [Contact], email as [Email], nric as [NRIC],  address as [Address], handle as [HandleCase], postedto as [Posted To] from PoliceAccount where status='available'", conn);
                da.Fill(ds);

                conn.Close();

                 return ds.Tables[0];               

   }
```

Below is basically how i sorting of the data that are displayed upon page load

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = Session["gridview"] as DataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {
            //Sort the data.
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            // dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression.ToString();
            this.GVPolice.DataSource = Session["gridview"];
            GVPolice.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {
        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }
```

Here is the paging wise

```
    protected void GVPolice_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        GVPolice.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GVPolice.DataBind();
    }
```

This is then how i searched the information out

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        //conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI";
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select policeid as [Police ID], fullname as [Full Name], contact as [Contact], email as [Email], nric as [NRIC],  address as [Address], handle as [HandleCase], postedto as [Posted To] from PoliceAccount where status='available' and " + ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text + " like '%" + txtData.Text + "%'", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

        GVPolice.DataSource = ds.Copy();
        GVPolice.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

As you can see from my Searched button, i rebind my entire gridview, which i believe it should call the sort/page codes again but unfortunately it doesn't. In fact, when i attempt to sort/page, it will display out the page_load information that was displayed. I would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me on how to enable to page/sort for just the searched gridview when a search attempt was done.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have placed the Page Load code inside of an if block as follows

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Session["gridview"] = DataBindByDataSet();
    GVPolice.DataSource = Session["gridview"];
    GVPolice.DataBind();

    using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connAdd.Open();

        var sql = "select policeid as [Police ID], fullname as [Full Name], contact as [Contact], email as [Email], nric as [NRIC],  address as [Address], handle as [HandleCase], postedto as [Posted To] from PoliceAccount where status='available'";
        using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
        {
            DataSet dsSel = new DataSet();
            cmdAdd.Fill(dsSel);
            GVPolice.DataSource = dsSel;
            GVPolice.DataBind();
        }
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

and in `btnSearch_Click` event store the filtered data in the session as follows because you are using the `Session["gridview"]` to sort the data in `GridView1_Sorting` event.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .......
    .......

    GVPolice.DataSource = ds.Copy();
    GVPolice.DataBind();

    Session["gridview"] = ds.Tables[0];

    conn.Close()
}
```

now we will be able to sort the filtered data.

Inorder to paging to be worked properly for filtered data, we need to change the `GVPolice_PageIndexChanging` event as follows.

```
protected void GVPolice_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GVPolice.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GVPolice.DataSource = Session["gridview"];
    GVPolice.DataBind();
}
```